# Azure Standard Internal Load Balancer backend machines partial internet access

Tags: azure, azure-load-balancer

Whenever i'm adding a VM(Windows/Linux) to the backend pool of a Standard(not basic) Internal load balancer, the VM loses internet access(outbound) to all the internet sites(example: www.google.co.in) except Microsoft sites(bing.com).

Things i have tried:
1. Created Health probe and load balancing rules to verify the load balancing is happening - and yes the load balancing works but no internet access
2. DisableOutboundSNAT on the Rule - load balancing works but no internet access
3. Created NSG to allow all outbound traffic (which is enabled by default) - no luck

Comment: Check the DNS server, if BING is working - then its mostly to do with DNS settings

Comment: @harishr There is no dns issue, as soon as i remove the VM from Load Balancer's backend pool, internet works. The problem occurs only when i add the VM to Load Balancer Backend pool and only if the Load Balancer SKU is standard(it works for Basic as mentioned in the question)

Comment: Yes, but what are the rules attached to LB, can you add them to the question, also rules attached to VM (thru NIC or Subnet)

Comment: @harishr The LB has Load Balancing rule on port 80 and same on Health probe. I have attached the NSG details below. NSG is applied only on VM and not on a subnet. NSG img url : https://imgur.com/a/IHqFqW7

Comment: This seems to be a bug as few more people seems to be facing the same issue. please try to create above scenario with 1.  ILB Std and 1 VM . https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/c324d260-d0a6-4c0d-ad66-82e52df0b715/unable-to-access-to-internet-with-a-standard-load-balancer?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows

Answer (score 3):

Finally this issue is resolved.
This is by design as mentioned on [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-outbound-connections):

So for a conclusion, if we want to access internet from the VM behind a Standard ILB, we need to associate a Public IP to the VM. ( I tested it and it worked).

Also, this seems a very good design as VM is completely private(no outbound implicitly) when it is behind a Standard Load Balancer.

Thanks to [Micah](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/micah%20mckittrick/?ws=usercard-mini) for resolving this on [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/d8b79d69-37c3-4694-86f7-9ee650e3a52c/azure-ilb-outbound-traffic?forum=WAVirtualMachinesVirtualNetwork) post.

Comment: It's worth noting that you have three options in total, to provide your VMs with outbound Internet access:
1) Directly associate an Instance Level Public IP to each VM
2) Associate a Public IP to the Standard Load Balancer, and create outbound rules (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-outbound-rules-overview)
3) Apply a Route for 0.0.0.0./0 on the Subnet and push the traffic to an Azure Firewall or 3rd Party NVA